# Windows software to intercept browser calls

Tags: windows, web-browser, internet, url, launcher

In Windows, when an application tries to load a web page, the default browser is loaded without any user interaction.

Can anyone recommend Windows software that will intercept the call before the browser is loaded and offer the user a prompt asking whether or not they want to load the URL?

Ideally, but not required, the software could allow certain user-specified applications to load URLs without prompting.

Also, ideally, but not required, is the ability to block the calls when a browser is not loaded, but allow the calls if the browser is already loaded.

Must be compatible with Windows 7.

*(If you are familiar with Android, you are probably aware that this functionality is more-or-less built into that operating system.)*

Comment: Windows 10 has this too.